# ZF2: how to implement different configs for production, staging etc?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, config

In the sceleton application that I've downloaded from github there is a file 
module/Application/config/module.config.php

```
return array(
    'layout'                => 'layout/layout.phtml',
    'display_exceptions'    => true,
    'di'                    => array(
        'instance' => array(
        'alias' => array(....
```

this file is used in module/Application/module.php:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}
```

How to create 3 different configs depending on domain (production, staging, development)? It seems in ZF1 env vars has been used, but I don't know how to do that in zf2 module.
Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Create a file called `development.config.php` in `application/config/autoload` and this will be loaded after all the modules' config files have been loaded. As a result, you can override anything the merged configuration by adding the relevant keys to this file.

The name of the file loaded is `{APPLICATION_ENV}.config.php`, so you can create `production.config.php`, etc.

Note that you may have to change the glob in `index.php` as it's unclear if the Skeleton application will work out of the box with APPLICATION_ENV or not at this stage of the development of ZF2 (early April 2012).

Answer (score 4):

it seems to work with a simple .htaccess change. :

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

I don't know if staging will work, but production and development work out of the box.
I think it works through the event listener, but don't ask me how, I haven't gotten that far yet.